# 2015 Macbook Pro specifically on home wifi, DNS/Connection problems

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, dns

When connected to my home network (Uk Sky, with Sky router) I have consistent unreliable connection on my 2015 Macbook Pro Retina 13 inch.

The problems include extended periods `resolving host...` while loading webpages, failed dns lookups on every site and intermittent no network connection messages on both safari and google chrome. The problem usually corrects itself at random after around a short period of time refreshing and joining and rejoining the network or by d.

My DNS server is set to Google's dns at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. I have flushed my dns caches on browsers and on my machine.

I have removed all saved networks on my machine and rejoined the problem local network.

As far as I am aware no other devices connected to my home wifi have any similar issues. I have also never had any similar issues with this machine on any other network.

The problems are not browser specific.

I have difficulty finding relevant help online as most problems with similar symptoms have browser specific fixes.

I have also accessed my router settings at 192.168.0.1 and cannot find anything untoward or immediately obvious to fix.

Note that my macbook was purchased in the USA and I reside in the UK.

I am now at an absolute loss as to what to try next or how to diagnose the issue so any suggestion would be appreciated.